# is there any way to turn off gdb's buffer checking for input?

Tags: c, gdb

I am learning to cause buffer overflows for a security class using GDB. I have an input file that successfully causes a program to jump to an unauthorized function by writing a buffer overflow when I feed it as input like this:

```
sh myFile.txt | ./myProgram
```

Now I want to examine the unauthorized function using GDB. But when I feed myFile as input to GDB using the either the [tty command or using <](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Input_002fOutput.html)  GDB only takes a middle 20-bytes of my input to fill the 20-byte buffer. It seems like GDB is "checking" the buffer size of the input.

1. Is that what gdb is doing?
2. If so, is there way to turn it off?

The C code looks like this:

```
  char one[20];
  char two[20];

  printf("..."); fflush(stdout);
  gets(one);   //only takes 20 bytes from the middle of printf "morethan20bytes..." from input file
  printf("..."); fflush(stdout);
  gets(two);   //only takes 20 bytes from the middle of printf "morethan20bytes..." from input file
```

Comment: How are you determining that behaviour?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I examine the bit-level contents of buffer one and two using the x command. I then convert the hex i see to ascii and can tell that is is only taking 20 char from the middle of the input.

Comment: The memory contents may have been overwritten, but since GDB knows of the array sizes it will only display that. You might be able to use an out-of-range index to examine outside the arrays, or else cast to a pointer and add an offset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gdb isn't "taking" anything. It just assumes you only want to see the contents of "one" and nothing more.

Are you aware of the {type}expr@num notation for printing variables in the debugger?  For example, to see the contents of "one" past the 20th index in the buffer:

```
(gdb) next
...10     gets(one);   //only takes last 20 bytes of printf "morethan20bytes..." from input file
(gdb) next
BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH   # <== simulating input
11    printf("..."); fflush(stdout);

(gdb) print one
$2 = "BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH"
```

Above, it appears that "one" only has 20 chars in it. But that's because gdb is assuming you only want to see 20 bytes.

Let's now print out the first 40 characters that start at the memory address of "one"

```
(gdb) print {char}one@40
$3 = "BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH"
```

You can clearly see that it goes past the buffer length

```
(gdb) print two
$4 = "BLAHBLAHBLAH\000\000\000\000\000\000\000"
```

And you can see that the overrun wrote into into "two" as well.

```
(gdb) x one
0x7fffffffe750: 0x48414c42
(gdb) print {char}0x7fffffffe750@40
$6 = "BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH"
```

Above you can see we can do the same thing with memory addresses.